# Selecting data from a one-to-many relationship table

Tags: sql-server

Admins, please note although it shares the same structure from the question I posted earlier about hierarchical data but it is a completely different question. I have the following tables:

**Teachers:**

```
+------+--------+
|  id  | deptId |
+------+--------+
|  1   |    2   |
+------+--------+
|  2   |    1   |
+------+--------+
```

**Department:**

```
+------+-----------+
|  id  | contactId |
+------+-----------+
|  1   |     2     |
+------+-----------+
|  2   |     6     |
+------+-----------+
```

**Contact:**

```
+----+--------------------+
| id | nonImportantColumn |
+----+--------------------+
| 2  |   street street    |
+----+--------------------+
| 4  |   street2street    |
+----+--------------------+
```

**SchoolBranch:**

```
+----+-----------+----------------+
| id | contactId | parentBranchId |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 3  |    2      |     null       |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 4  |    5      |     3          |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 5  |    7      |     null       |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 6  |    2      |     3          |
+----+-----------+----------------+
```

Given a teacher's ID let's say 2, I am trying to get the teacher's linked branch, which should be BranchID:3 row but I am receving an extra row for BranchID:6 because it also shares the same contactId.

I am using SQL Server v 18, in case it helps.
I have tried this query

```
select b.* from SchoolBranch b where b.contactId = (
    select c.id from  Contact c 
        inner join Department d on c.id = d.contactId
        inner join Teachers t on d.id = t.deptId
    where t.id = 2
    )
```

but it returns two rows instead of one. **Here is [dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d25953d96e62d1f6c1393b6aae7b5275)**

Comment: From your example, the inner query returns 2, therefore, the outer query executes like this: `select b.* from SchoolBranch b where b.contactId = 2`. Since the table `SchoolBranch` has two rows with `contactId` equals 2, your final resultset has two rows. I can't see the problem. Did I miss something?

Comment: Your output is correct.On what basis you should get branchid 3 and not 6.Tell the requirement/